# Trying to click on a checkbox when there are multiple checkboxes

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I am currently using pyautogui to automate a web application. I am very new to the software so every single step has been a learning experiennce. I am currently trying to select a specific checkbox however since there are multiple check boxes I am not able to do so. I am currently using a screenshot of the checkbox icon in order to click on it so I figured this was my problem. Is there anyway in pyautogui to select a specific image even if there are duplicates present?

I've tried playing around with the coordinates, but since this application needs to be as user friendly as possible I thought setting specific coordinates could be tricky.

Checkcoords=pyautogui.locateOnScreen("checkbox.png"#Locate the checkbox, but since there are multiple checkboxes it just goes to the first one present and not the one that i need
pyatuogui.click(Checkcoords) # used to click the checkbox

Not getting any error messages, just goes to the wrong checkbox.

Comment: Each checkbox certainly has a different `name` html attribute.  Can you locate the checkboxes by their name?

Comment: If you can modify the website, You can Add ID's(unique) which you can make unique.
You can also get a list of checkboxes rather than first checkbox.